# Website make defualt first letter in first word of evry sequence in evry element

Tags: css

Want to make capitals letters by default generated by website . I have a problem my code make first letter capital in  other else but in attachemnt  and span  it doesn't work . i make it in * becouse in attachment body doesnt work. I want do it only for first word in every seqience  Here is my co

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@100&display=swap");
/* 
*/
body {
    background: rgb(43, 42, 42);
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: "Noto Sans JP", sans-serif;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*::first-letter {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <!-- style  -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <!-- shortcut icon / title-->
        <title>AAAA</title>
        <link rel="icon" sizes="any" href="images/skyview.jpg" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>first letter big</h1>
            <h1>first letter big</h1>
            <a href="#">no big first letter</a>
        </div>
        <span>no big first letter</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

de

Comment: first-letter will apply to only block elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css selector `::first-letter`doesn't work on inline element as span

one way to solve your issue is to apply `display:block` or `display:inline-block` on wanted element

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@100&display=swap");
/* 
*/
body {
    background: rgb(43, 42, 42);
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: "Noto Sans JP", sans-serif;
}

span, a {
  display:block;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::first-letter {
border: solid red 1px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <!-- style  -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <!-- shortcut icon / title-->
        <title>AAAA</title>
        <link rel="icon" sizes="any" href="images/skyview.jpg" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>first letter big</h1>
            <h1>first letter big</h1>
            <a href="#">no big first letter</a>
        </div>
        <span>no big first letter</span>
    </body>
</html>
```